# How can I name a function using a variable?

Tags: python

How can I set the name of a function using a string from a list?

```
listname = ["first", "second"]

def listname[0]():
    (...)
```

After that the error appears

```
SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are asking. Do you mean, you want to create functions named dynamically? Like the name of the function is stored in a list and then you iterate over that list and create the function with the name?

Comment: Notice that function names are not special, they're just variables that happen to contain functions, and generating variables dynamically is usually not a good idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: You definitely do not want to do this.

Comment: What is your underlying goal? What do you aim to accomplish once you figure this out? This is a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): "...asking about your attempted *solution* rather than your actual *problem*. That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y."

Comment: Manually. 1) Create functions with an internal naming scheme (`x`, `y`, whatever) 2) use a dict to associate your desired name with that function: `mapping={'my_name_for_x':x, 'my_name_for_y':y}` 3) call with `mapping['my_name_for_x']()`

Comment: See [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](https://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using python's [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) and [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

You can store the function code in a string like:

```py
generic_func_code="""\
def func_name(x):
    return x+1"""
```

Then replace the function name using `str.replace()` and execute the newly created string.

```py
func_code=generic_func_code.replace('func_name', listname[0])
exec(func_code)
# function named listname[0] has been created
```

However, as pointed out by [@Ture Pålsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4177009/ture-p%c3%a5lsson) ​this [probably isn't a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)